# Get Virtual machine tags with curl commande

Tags: shell, curl, virtual-machine, vsphere, vcenter

For my script I would like to get the tags of a VM. I'm able to get the details of a virtual machine with this curl command :

```
curl -k -s --request GET \
          --url https://XXXXX/rest/vcenter/vm/vm-31623 \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --cookie vmware-api-session-id=$session_ID
```

But I would like to get the tags for the VM and they are not in the result of this command.

There is someone to show me the curl command to get that?

Answer (score 0):

vSphere Automation's CIS service should be able to get what you need. Specifically, [list-attached-tags-on-objects](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/cis/api/cis/tagging/tag-associationactionlist-attached-tags-on-objects/post/)

Example:

```
curl -k -s --request POST \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --cookie vmware-api-session-id=$session_ID \
          --url https://XXXXX/api/cis/tagging/tag-association?action=list-attached-tags-on-objects
          --data { "object_ids": [ { "id": "vm-31623", "type": "vm" } ] }
```